# How do i get the requestmapping value in the controller?

Tags: spring-mvc

In the controller , i have this code,
somehow, i want to get the request Mapping value "search".
How is it possible ?

```
 @RequestMapping("/search/")     
 public Map searchWithSearchTerm(@RequestParam("name") String name) {    
        // more code here     
 }
```

Comment: could you expand on your use case please?  I'm trying to figure out what you're trying to get here, because having search doesn't seem useful other than to log or use the full path, in which case you can just get the path from the request as ankit instructed

Answer (score 34):

If you want the pattern, you can try `HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE`:

```
@RequestMapping({"/search/{subpath}/other", "/find/other/{subpath}"})
public Map searchWithSearchTerm(@PathVariable("subpath") String subpath,
                                             @RequestParam("name") String name) {

    String pattern = (String) request.getAttribute(
                                 HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);
    // pattern will be either "/search/{subpath}/other" or
    // "/find/other/{subpath}", depending on the url requested
    System.out.println("Pattern matched: "+pattern);

}
```

Comment: Note, the value of the `BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE` attribute will include a trailing slash if the matched URL includes a trailing slash [1].

[1] https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18207

Answer (score 26):

It seems you are looking for the path that this request has matched, then you can directly get it from servlet path

```
@RequestMapping("/search/")     
 public Map searchWithSearchTerm(@RequestParam("name") String name, HttpServletRequest request) {    
String path = request.getServletPath();
        // more code here     
 }
```

Comment: lets say the req mapping was something like @RequestMapping("/search/{userId}")
In this case, we will get /search/1 and not /search/{id} using the .getServletPath. Any idea on how we can get  /search/{id}?

Comment: Why would you want to do that.. its just a variable name..

Comment: @AnkitBansal In my case I needed it to collect request metrics. We have multiple request mappings handled by the same method. So with OPs example the metric tag "uri" should be set to "/search/{userId}" and not "search/1", "search/2", "search/3". No idea what OPs use case was but there are definitely reasons why you'd just want to have the pattern without variable values.

Answer (score 21):

Having a controller like

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/web/objet")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save")
    public String save(...) {
        ....
    }
}
```

You cant get the controller base requestMapping using reflection

```
// Controller requestMapping
String controllerMapping = this.getClass().getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class).value()[0];
```

or the method requestMapping (from inside a method) with reflection too

```
//Method requestMapping
String methodMapping = new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class).value()[0];
```

Obviously works with an in requestMapping single value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is useful when using an abstract base controller with logic inside that needs the request mapping of the inheriting, concrete, controller classes

Comment: Class method `public <A extends Annotation> A getAnnotation(Class<A> annotationClass)`  the annotation must extends `Annotation` while `RequestMapping` does not. Is that really available `class.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class)`?

Comment: RequestMapping does not? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html

Comment: @Tiina I had to cast the result of `getAnnotation()` to a `RequestMapping` object in order to use the `.value()` method and grab the first entry. Example: `String requestMapping = ((RequestMapping) testControllerClass.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class)).value()[0];`

Comment: This gets the literal value assigned to the annotation but it doesn't get the resolved value at run time. My situation is assigning the annotation to the property value of spring.application.name assigned in application.yml but when I use this above mentioned code it resolves the value of the annotation to "${spring.application.name}" rather than it's resolved value at runtime. I'll edit this comment if I figure this out.

Comment: I ended up injecting the name into the controller by creating a bean that takes the property value. So now it's a configuration class thing to sort out. Not completely ideal, but better than hard coding it.

Answer (score 2):

```
@RequestMapping("foo/bar/blub")     
public Map searchWithSearchTerm(@RequestParam("name") String name, HttpServletRequest request) {
  // delivers the path without context root 
  // mapping = "/foo/bar/blub"
  String mapping = request.getPathInfo();
  // more code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Spring 3.1 and above you can use `ServletUriComponentsBuilder`

```
@RequestMapping("/search/")     
     public ResponseEntity<?> searchWithSearchTerm(@RequestParam("name") String name) {  
         UriComponentsBuilder builder = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest();
         System.out.println(builder.buildAndExpand().getPath());
         return new ResponseEntity<String>("OK", HttpStatus.OK);
     }
```