# Spring restful API, is there a method being used like router to get other method's end points or URL?

Tags: java, spring, rest, url, routes

```
@RequestMapping("/accounts")
public class controller {
    @GetMapping("/get/{id}")
    public final ResponseEntity<?> getHandler(){
    }
    @PostMapping(value = "/create")
    public final ResponseEntity<?> createHandler(){
    /*
     trying to use some spring library methods to get the url string of 
     '/accounts/get/{id}' instead of manually hard coding it 
    */
    }
}
```

This is the mock code, now I am in createHandler, after finishing creating something, then I want to return a header including an URL string, but I don't want to manually concat this URL string ('/accounts/get/{id}') which is the end point of method `getHandler()`, so I am wondering if there is a method to use to achieve that? I know `request.getRequestURI()`, but that is only for the URI in the current context.

More explanation: if there is some library or framework with the implementation of route:

`Routes.Accounts.get(1234)`

which return the URL for the accounts get

`/api/accounts/1234`

Answer (score 0):

The idea is, that you don't need to specify `get` or `create` (verbs are a big no-no in REST).

Imagine this:

```
@RequestMapping("/accounts")
public class controller {
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public final ResponseEntity<?> getHandler(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        //just to illustrate
        return complicatedHandlerCalculation(id).asResponse();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public final ResponseEntity<?> createHandler() {
        //return a 204 Response, containing the URI from getHandler, with {id} resolved to the id from your database (or wherever).
    }
}
```

This would be accessible like `HTTP-GET: /api/accounts/1` and `HTTP-POST: /api/accounts`, the latter would return an URI for `/api/accounts/2` (what can be gotten with `HTTP-GET` or updated/modified with `HTTP-PUT`)

To resolve this URI, you could use reflection and evaluate the annotations on the corresponding class/methods like Jersey does.

A Spring equivalent could be:

```
// Controller requestMapping
String controllerMapping = this.getClass().getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class).value()[0];
```

and

```
//Method requestMapping
String methodMapping = new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getAnnotation(GetMapping.class).value()[0];
```

taken from [How do i get the requestmapping value in the controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796545/how-do-i-get-the-requestmapping-value-in-the-controller)

Comment: That is a solution, but the situation is I only know the method name, where I want to source the request mapping url, and don't know what is the index of the annotations like `GetMapping` or `RequestMapping` in this class. So I am wondering if there is a router like some JS library could be used for registering all method name and the end point, after that, I could call it to get the url by method name, like `Routes.Accounts.get(1234)` which return the URL for the accounts get

`/api/accounts/1234`

Comment: do you want this? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29
with that you get a Method by name. (Maybe outdated, but I think still valid)